# Launching zookeeper from ssh

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, apache-zookeeper

When I run

```
~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground
```

zookeeper launches on my box with no issues but when I run

```
ssh -l username hostname '~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground'
```

I get the message zkServer.sh: line 131: java: not found

If I ssh into that box first and then run the command at the top it works. I cannot figure out why my ssh command fails then (the second one). Shouldn't it all be the same whether I ssh into the box first or try to do it all in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
ssh -l username hostname 'bash -l -c "~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground"'
```

or:

```
ssh -l username hostname 'bash -i -c "~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkServer.sh start-foreground"'
```

Comment: The top one with -l and -c worked! I also had to remove the start-foreground and put it back to just start. It was sooooo tricky, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there any way to update a key using this same logic such as `ssh -l username hostname '~/zookeeper-3.4.6/bin/zkCli.sh set mykey 1`? Thanks

Comment: @LucasRezende: I suggest to start a new question.